# How to arrange the html file and use all the other css and javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The whole project can be found here, I added it to GitHub:

https://github.com/chocolade1972/Google-Maps-Api-Development

For making it easier to see and find visually I created for each part a folder and put it's files inside.

[image: folders]

in each folder: Load Bar , Map, Range Slider there is two files: css and js

this is the index.html content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <link href="Map/map.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Load Bar/loadbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#0d0f07;">

  

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

</body>

<script src="Map/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Load Bar/loadbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
  <div class="center-screen">
  <h1 id="loading-message">...טוען מפה</h1>
   <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
   <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="input-range" type="range" value="50" min="1" max="100">
  <span class="range-value"></span>
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Range Slider/rangeslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

the Load Bar and the Range Slider are executing fine, but the map is never loading.

this is the map css content file:

```
#map
    {
        width: 1600px;
        height:850px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 48%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    
    #map.fullscreen {
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

and the map content of the javascript file:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"

    function initMap() {
        // The location of Uluru
        const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: uluru,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          
          options: {
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  }
        });
    
        const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
            bounds: {
                north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
                south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
                west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
                east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
            },
          });
      
} 
      window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: The `<script>` element to load the Google Maps API needs to be a `<script>` element **in your HTML document**. It is **HTML**. It is not JavaScript. It does not go in your JavaScript file.

Comment: @Quentin but it does with the tag <script> already in the html.  <script src="Map/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first add in your html file in the `<body>` just before `<script src="Map/map.js"></script>` the script tag to be able to use Google Maps API:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"></script>
```

Then remove this url (maps.google...) from the JS file. It has nothing to do here.

Another problem is that there is not an element with id "map" in your page. So add in the `<body>` before the script tags the following for instance:

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I tried, not working. I did put the lines as you mentioned and removed that line from the javascript file.   maybe the problem is the line in the javascript file of the map: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") maybe the elemenybyid is not "map" because I moved it to a file?

Comment: I found the other problem that you have. There is not an element with id "map" in your page!! Check back my answer